# IPUtilization widget is not populating in Hygieia. Also, No data populating for cloud_subnetwork cloud_virtual_network documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hygieia

I am new to Hygieia. I have setup Hygieia (https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia) as per the documentation and I could start my application and see the dashboard successfully. In Hygieia-Dashboard, I could see values coming for all widget items (say utilization, instances stoped, and so on.) **except the IP Utilization widget**. When i see the mongodb that i configured with this (after I ran AWS module) i could see data for most of the documents except the cloud_subnetwork and cloud_virtual_network. Is this causing the issue?

Can anyone please assist me for populating IPUtilization widget ?
if I am still missing with anything? Anyfurther configuration to be made for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue., i.e., we need to fetch values for subnets and virtual_networks by using the AmazonEC2Client's instances by calling its describeSubnets() and describeVpcs() respectively and save these to database. After this, we could see values in the IPUtilization widgets. Hope this helps!